# my own logstash filter doesn't extract the input field value correctly

Tags: ruby, logstash

I have built my own plugin filter for logstash. The principle of this filter is to get some coordinates (x,y) formated in a coordinates system called "lambertII" and to convert them in gps system (latitude, longitude). Here is an example:

```
lambert {
    convert => ["lambertII", x, y]
    latitude => ["lat"] #return as output latitude
    longitude => ["long"] #return as output longitude
}
```

It works well when I write for instance:

```
 convert => ["LambertII", 2478517.33, 547536.68]
```

However, when I extract data from a json file as shown below

```
{"x":2478517.33, "y":547536.68}
{"x":2699120.65, "y":544959.56}
```

but it does not work, when I write:

```
convert => ["LambertII", "%{[x]}", "%{[y]}"]
```

or

```
convert => ["LambertII", "%{x}", "%{y}"]
```

Indeed, my ruby code does not extract the float value from the expressions "%{[..]}" or "%{..}" but it interprets them like string expressions.

I have already seen this following link but it didn't solve my problem: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#event-dependent-configuration

I didn't find out how to solve this problem. I would be very thankful for any help.

Thank you for your attention and your help !

Comment: I can provide my ruby code lambert.rb if it is usefull

Comment: Could you provide your code, please? A link to a https://gist.github.com/ would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are not calling event.sprintf() in lambert.rb. use it and it shoudl work !